# Split string to multiple column

Tags: postgresql

```
|assoc_name|
------------
|meena,malhotra
|sita,sharma

|assoc_name|assoc_last_name|
----------------------------
|meena     | malhotra     |
|sita      | sharma       |
```

`SELECT split_part(assoc_name,',','1') AS Part1 from mytable;`
This worked but ho do i save the output to a different column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make two calls to `SPLIT_PART`, one for each desired column:

```
SELECT
    SPLIT_PART(assoc_name, ',', 1) AS assoc_name,
    SPLIT_PART(assoc_name, ',', 2) AS assoc_last_name
FROM mytable;
```

If you want to persist this view in a database table, then try using `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`, using the above select:

```
INSERT INTO someOtherTable (assoc_name, assoc_last_name)
SELECT
    SPLIT_PART(assoc_name, ',', 1),
    SPLIT_PART(assoc_name, ',', 2)
FROM mytable;
```

To handle the case where one/both of the above calls to `SPLIT_PART` might return `NULL`, and the target column be non nullable, then consider using `COALESCE`:

```
INSERT INTO someOtherTable (assoc_name, assoc_last_name)
SELECT
    COALESCE(SPLIT_PART(assoc_name, ',', 1), ''),
    COALESCE(SPLIT_PART(assoc_name, ',', 2), '')
FROM mytable;
```

Comment: that dint get saved to my db

Comment: I have a column assoc_last_name.. I want to split and save the value

Comment: @DimpleMathew Check my updated answer.  Just insert this new information into another table.

Comment: Hey its throwing error  Failing row contains (Gowrisankar, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, Hemalatha).

Comment: Then you're not running the code in my answer, which involves only two columns.

Comment: ERROR:  null value in column "associate_nbr" violates not-null constraint

Comment: Table has multiple columns... one column is assoc_name which i want to split.

Comment: Try wrapping the calls to `SPLIT_PART` using `COALESCE`, e.g. `COALESCE(SPLIT_PART(assoc_name, ',', 1), '')` ... this would prevent nulls from being inserted, instead inserting empty string.

Comment: I need to create another table for this?

Comment: all the columns have some value this wont remove data from my table ryt?

Comment: I have answered your original question.  You may open a new question if you still have other problems.